# How to analyze webalizer's dns_cache.db file under windows?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, cache

I am trying to take a look at the dns_cache.db file that is generated by webalizer when doing DNS lookups to find out why some host files seem not to be resolved resolved properly.

Is there any way I can do that under windows (wcmgr does not work there)?

Thank you & regards,
flickaswitch

Answer (score 0):

That's probably going to be a Berkeley DB file.  You should be able to use perl or python's berkeley DB interfaces to get the contents.

[Perl DBI Example](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2004/09/12/embedded.html)

There's more information about Berkeley DB at:

[Oracle Berkely DB Pages](http://www.oracle.com/database/berkeley-db/)